# How do I get how much storage account is used report from azure to interact with power bi?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-storage

I am trying to get all the storage accounts used capacity and interact that data to power bi to generate reports.

I have tried to query the data but I am new to azure. I have tried to download it to excel and then work but excel doesn't comprehend with TiB values and I need to automate this so that it can generate report every month

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to get all the storage accounts used capacity and interact that data to power bi to generate reports

You can use [log analytic workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-workspace-overview) to get the storage account used capacity.

You can use the below **KQL** query to get the output in used capacity and availability.

**Query:**

```
AzureMetrics  
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"  
| summarize Totalvalue = sum(Total) by MetricName
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can use the query below if you need it in **percentage**.

**Query**

```
AzureMetrics  
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"  
| summarize Totalvalue = sum(Total) by MetricName| as T  
| extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Totalvalue / toscalar(T | summarize sum(Totalvalue)), 2)
```

**Output:**
[image]

For time range you can use the custom to select the date for one month.

[image]

You can export to Powerbi by clicking export in your portal.

[image]